# console.log doesnt log anything in the portal

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

**Why aren't any logging executions going into the log?**

From within the portal, I'm attempting to log: `console.log('hello');`:

[image]

However, nothing is come through to the console within the browser. The only thing coming through are the log events that are built in:

[image]

**How do we log to the portal?**

Comment: I think you probably have some errors occurring somewhere else in your app before index.js ever gets to run. Perhaps some middleware?

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `context.log("hello");`